# android - getting remote JSON throws error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, json, httpclient

I'm trying to **load a remote file** and I have to use `HttpClient.execute` which always throws an error. Any ideas?

Function I'm using:

```
private void loadCol3(Map.Entry<String, String> map) {
    LinearLayout col3 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.col3);
    String result = null;
    col3.removeAllViews();

    Log.d(TAG, "start load col 3");

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://video.foxbusiness.com/v/feed/playlist/"+map.getValue()+".js?template=fox&callback=?");
    ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();  

    try {  
        result = httpclient.execute(request, handler);  
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "httpclient.execute failed");
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

    try {
        JSONObject completeJSONObj = new JSONObject(result);
        String json = completeJSONObj.toString();
        Log.d(TAG, json);
        JSONObject results = completeJSONObj.getJSONObject("results");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.d(TAG,"JSON parsing error:" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.tv"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

        <activity android:name=".MyActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Current log when ran:

```
07-31 17:56:17.175: DEBUG/log_tag(10869): start load col 3
07-31 17:56:17.205: DEBUG/log_tag(10869): httpclient.execute failed
```

Last line of console:

```
[2011-07-31 11:57:57 - My app] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.tv/.MyActivity }
```

** edit - stacktraces **

```
07-31 18:11:47.475: WARN/System.err(11083): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
07-31 18:11:47.475: WARN/System.err(11083):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1077)
07-31 18:11:47.475: WARN/System.err(11083):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:477)
07-31 18:11:47.475: WARN/System.err(11083):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:277)
07-31 18:11:47.475: WARN/System.err(11083):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:249)
07-31 18:11:47.475: WARN/System.err(11083):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:136)
07-31 18:11:47.475: WARN/System.err(11083):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
07-31 18:11:47.475: WARN/System.err(11083):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
07-31 18:11:47.475: WARN/System.err(11083):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
07-31 18:11:47.475: WARN/System.err(11083):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
07-31 18:11:47.475: WARN/System.err(11083):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:653)
07-31 18:11:47.475: WARN/System.err(11083):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:627)
07-31 18:11:47.475: WARN/System.err(11083):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:616)
07-31 18:11:47.475: WARN/System.err(11083):     at com.foxbusiness.tv.FOXBusinessActivity.loadCol3(FOXBusinessActivity.java:134)
07-31 18:11:47.475: WARN/System.err(11083):     at com.foxbusiness.tv.FOXBusinessActivity.access$1(FOXBusinessActivity.java:121)
07-31 18:11:47.475: WARN/System.err(11083):     at com.foxbusiness.tv.FOXBusinessActivity$2.onClick(FOXBusinessActivity.java:113)
07-31 18:11:47.475: WARN/System.err(11083):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3110)
07-31 18:11:47.475: WARN/System.err(11083):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11928)
07-31 18:11:47.485: WARN/System.err(11083):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-31 18:11:47.485: WARN/System.err(11083):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-31 18:11:47.485: WARN/System.err(11083):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
07-31 18:11:47.485: WARN/System.err(11083):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
07-31 18:11:47.485: WARN/System.err(11083):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-31 18:11:47.485: WARN/System.err(11083):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
07-31 18:11:47.485: WARN/System.err(11083):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
07-31 18:11:47.485: WARN/System.err(11083):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
07-31 18:11:47.485: WARN/System.err(11083):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

07-31 18:09:26.915: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11024): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-31 18:09:26.915: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11024): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-31 18:09:26.915: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11024):     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:112)
07-31 18:09:26.915: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11024):     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:90)
07-31 18:09:26.915: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11024):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)
07-31 18:09:26.915: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11024):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
07-31 18:09:26.915: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11024):     at com.example.tv.MyActivity.loadCol3(MyActivity.java:142)
07-31 18:09:26.915: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11024):     at com.example.tv.MyActivity.access$1(MyActivity.java:121)
07-31 18:09:26.915: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11024):     at com.example.tv.MyActivity$2.onClick(MyActivity.java:113)
07-31 18:09:26.915: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11024):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3110)
07-31 18:09:26.915: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11024):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11928)
07-31 18:09:26.915: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11024):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-31 18:09:26.915: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11024):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-31 18:09:26.915: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11024):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
07-31 18:09:26.915: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11024):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
07-31 18:09:26.915: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11024):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-31 18:09:26.915: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11024):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
07-31 18:09:26.915: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11024):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
07-31 18:09:26.915: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11024):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
07-31 18:09:26.915: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11024):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: How about posting the stack trace that your code sent to the console immediately after "httpclient.execute failed"?

Comment: @Ted I see two stack traces in LogCat and I'm not sure which is which so I added them both in an edit. Hopefully that is what you are looking for.

Comment: There's to much delay. Your program crashes because you run a network operation in the main thread.

Comment: @Fredrik I'm not sure of your recommendation. Are you recommending that I put this code/function into another class and running it there?

Comment: Interesting find based on what @Fredrik said: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the `NullpointerException` because you access the `result` even when the GET method fails.

As for the `NetworkOnMainThreadException`, well the problem is exactly that: You do networking on the main thread. Run your GET request in either an `AsyncTask` or an `IntentService`.

Comment: I moved the **get** to an `AsyncTask` and ran `new MyClass.execute("http://someplace.com/json.js");` that fixed that issue. Thanks!